# Is there a reason to make discrete selections not cyclic

Tags: interface

Im talking mostly about menus in games, when using a controller. But also stuff like different desktops on an android device. Mostly those are coupled with transition animations, lasting between 1/4 to 1/2 a second, forcing the user to give multiple inputs when going from one end to the other.
I notice this is quite common, and I always wonder if the designer made a deliberate decision, or if he just didn't think about it.

**Example 1**
Think of an ingame menu, something like:

```
>Start
 Settings
 Help
 Quit
```

If you want this to be controllable with an analog stick, you need a delay when selecting the option. The senseble thing to me would be making the selection cyclic. I.e. pressing "up" when "Start" is selected would select "Quit", and pressing "down" when "Quit" is selected would select "Start". However, I quite often experience that pressing "up" while start is selected does simply nothing

**Example 2**
Think of different screens on a smartphone or table, something like

```
 ___  ___  ___  ___ 
/   \/   \/   \/   \
| 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 |
\___/\___/\___/\___/
```

where you switch between screens by swiping left or right. The sensible thing to me, would be that swiping right on screen 4 would bring you to screen 1. However, there are devices where swiping right on screen 4 does nothing.

And there are probably more enviroments where stuff like that occurs, e.g. smart TVs or anything else that let's you go through discrete selections (where "discrete" here just means "no sliders" or stuff like that.

Comment: I think I have an idea of what you're trying to convey however any examples or images would definitely make a lot more sense and be contextual to users who do not understand your question.

Comment: Ok, I've added two examples. Hope that makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is always context dependent. In your second example, the screens might represent a "Wizard" type structure with a distinctive **end**, menus that just represent a choice of equally important and equally leveld items should allow cyclic navigation. For example a TV allows cyclic navigation through channels. A configuration Activity inside an App will not want you to start over at the end.

My rule of thumb is: If the items are comparable and similar in function, enable the user to cycle around at the end.